When I tried to invoke a chaincode in the hyperledger fabric peer cli, I got Argument list too long error
I have deployed a go chaincode called CalculateCC which has a calculation function. I used shim package. The calculation function gets the arguments in array of string "[]string". When I try to call the calculation function by passing the args [] string (the total length is 209477, i got the following error, bash: /usr/local/bin/peer: Argument list too long.
Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

I guess you are hitting some system limits discussed in this unix.stackexchange question:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument
One solution would be to use a simple client application to invoke the transaction. This could be driven from the command-line as a substitute for the Fabric peer CLI command, which itself is a Go client application when invoked this way. You might consider using an input file or stdin for the arguments to avoid hitting the system limits on command argument length.
Documentation for the Fabric Gateway client API (Go, Node and Java implementations) is available here:
https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/
That documentation links to some pre-built sample applications that you should be able to adapt for your needs .
